# Problems with calling variables from settings.py in models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making an app that references static files in the database. For flexibilities sake I am going back and making the models relative based on the BASE_DIR.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class agency(models.Model):
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agency_flag = models.FilePathField(
        path=settings.BASE_DIR+"program/static/flags")
    agency_bio = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    agency_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='red')
    time = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agency_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Agencies"
```

As long as I only call the variable once it works fine. But there are 2 more models that need to call settings.BASE_DIR

```
class programs(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.FilePathField(
        path=settings.BASE_DIR+"program/static/programs")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Programs"

class shiptypes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='000000')
    image = models.FilePathField(
        path=settings.BASE_DIR+"program/static/shiptypes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ship Types"
```

Despite using settings.BASE_DIR completely identically, django throws the error "type object 'settings' has no attribute 'BASE_DIR' on all but the first reference. If I go and get rid of settings.BASE_DIR in programs and shiptypes makemigrations runs with no problems. I feel like it could be something really obvious but I can't see it.

Thanks! (also if you have a better way of handling this I'm all ears)

Comment: How are you importing settings?

Comment: The answer below worked.. momentarily. I'm now needing the base directory in views as well and it's giving me the same error.. the code I used is `from django.conf import settings`
so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you put something like `BASE_DIR = settings.BASE_DIR` at the start of the code and then use that instead?
Sorry I can't really test it myself...

Comment: One of those situations where you get so caught up in fixing you can't take a step back and have another look. How embarrassingly easy hahaha.

That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the issue is that you're importing from `django.conf` rather than your own settings module which may mean your setting hasn't been applied when you need it, simply just import from your own module

```
from my_app import settings
```